# java circular linked list swap not working for head

Tags: java, nodes, circular-list

I have a method for swapping two nodes of a circular linked list

- It takes 2 objects as arguments. The code works for cases when the
  either objects is of head's element

  ```
  public void exchange(E a, E b) {
   Node<E> head = tail.getNext();
   if(a == b)
       return;

   if(isEmpty() || size == 1) //no exchange if size is 1
       return;

   if(size == 2){   //if size is two, head will be tail and tail will be head
       rotate();
   }

   else{

      Node<E> currA = head, prevA = null;    //search for first node
           if(head.getElement() == a){
           Node<E> temp = head;
           while(!temp.getNext().equals(head)){
               temp = temp.getNext();
           }
           prevA = temp;

       }else if(tail.getElement() == a){
          currA = tail;
          while(!currA.getNext().equals(tail)){
              prevA = currA.getNext();
          }
      }else{
          while(!currA.getElement().equals(a)){
              prevA = currA;
              currA = currA.getNext();
              if(currA.getNext() == head)
                  break;
          }
      }

      Node<E> currB = head, prevB = null; //Search for second node
                if(currB.getElement() == b){
           Node<E> temp = head;
       while(!temp.getNext().equals(head)){
           temp = temp.getNext();
       }
       prevB = temp;

       }else if(tail.getElement() == b){
           currB = tail;
          while(!currB.getNext().equals(tail)){
              prevB = currB.getNext();
          }
       }else{
           while(!currB.getElement().equals(b)){
               prevB = currB;
               currB = currB.getNext();
               if(currB.getNext() == head)
                   break;
       }
   }
   System.out.println(currA.getElement() +" currentA"); //I get output for this
   System.out.println(currB.getElement() +" currentB");
   System.out.println(prevA.getElement() +" previousA");// Gives null pointer exception when object a is head 
   System.out.println(prevB.getElement() +" previousB");// Gives null pointer exception when object b is head
   prevA.setNext(currB);
   prevB.setNext(currA);
   Node<E> temp = currA.getNext();
   currA.setNext(currB.getNext());
   currB.setNext(temp);
   }
  ```

  }

My code is able to give and use currA (and currB)
**But** 
 If a is the same value as head, instead of being assigned prevA in the if statement, it comes as null pointer. The same happens if b is head's element, then prevB comes as null.(The code stops there)

Comment: a circular linked list has no head and tail, does it?

Comment: the code is incomplete (first line does not make sense)

Comment: I am sorry I have not posted the whole code because I did not want post unecessary code.

Comment: I have put the whole code. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Since Java doesn't support the equivalent of a pointer to pointer, you may want to create a dummy node to replace the tail reference. That way the code doesn't have to special case the tail reference, then update tail from the dummy node once the swap is completed.

Comment: In addition to head + tail issue when swapping nodes, there's also an issue depending if the nodes are adjacent or separated. 4 references can be used to deal with this. Two of the references "point" to the two "prior" nodes that "point" to the two nodes to be swapped, the other two references "point" to the two nodes to be swapped. If nodes are adjacent, then two of these four references will be duplicates, but that won't be an issue. First, swap the next pointers in the "prior" nodes that point to the nodes to be swapped, then swap the next pointers in the nodes being swapped.